# Default value v-model data

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to assign a default value to data?
lastName, firstName and avatar are each assigned to my form with v-model.
I need this to modify the user's profile, in order to avoid errors like undefined if he does not fill in the whole form.

it gives me error it can't find user, i don't know how to assign user to my data

```
export default {
  name: "ProfilC",
  data: function () {
    return {
      lastName: user.user_lastName,
      firstName: user.user_firstName,
      avatar: user.user_avatar,
    };
  },
computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: "userInfos",
    }),
  },
```

Comment: Like this? `firstName: user.user_firstName || '',`

Comment: lastName: user.user_lastName,
firstName: user.user_firstName,
avatar: user.user_avatar, this is what i would like to have, but it gives me error it can't find user, i don't know how to assign user to my data

Comment: ok i will look for the props thank you

Comment: i think its this.user, not user